# An exercise in Evans' PDE book chapter5

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I can't prove one exercise in this book: Suppose $U$ is connected and $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ satisfies $Du=0, a.e. in $ $U $. Prove $u$ is constant a.e. in $U$. How to use the fact that $U$ is connected? Can you give some help to me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Approximating by mollifiers you conclude that $u$ is constant (equal to some $a_x$) on some small ball $B(x;\epsilon_x)$ for each $x \in U$. You use connectedness to conclude that all the $a_x$'s are equal.

Comment: @Frank          Great! Thank you! Mollifiers are so powerful!

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is not connected you can represent $U$ as the union of disjoint sets. In each disjoint set $u$ might be a different constant. Hence, $u$ is not a constant function.

Regarding the proof you might find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Absolutely_Continuous_on_Lines_.28ACL.29_characterization_of_Sobolev_functions) characterization of Sobolev functions helpful.

Comment: Also thanks for your answer, I find it is inspiring too.